# SUM(CASE WHEN Products.ProductID in (show which product matched) SQL

Tags: sql, count, case

Here is my current SQL statement

```
SELECT
  Customers.Customer,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Products.ProductID in ('ab6','ab5','ab4','ab3','ab2','ab1','abc'.......many others THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Product_10,
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Products ON Customers.ProductID = Products.ProductID
GROUP BY Customers.Customer
```

So basically it will count these items but I want the results to show me which one it matched whether it be all of them or one of them. Is this possible?

Comment: how do you want it to list the ones it matches on?  separate rows? comma separated list?  and what RDBMS? (MSSQL? ORacle, DB2? mySQL?)  It would help to understand your expected output.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most databases have a way of combining strings.  In MySQL, the function is `group_concat()`, so you can get what you want using:

```
SELECT c.Customer,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.ProductID in ('ab6','ab5','ab4','ab3','ab2','ab1','abc'.......many others THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Product_10,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.ProductId)
FROM Customers c INNER JOIN
     Products p
     ON c.ProductID = p.ProductID
GROUP BY c.Customer;
```

By the way, you have a problem with your data model.  Your query suggests that a customer can have multiple rows in the `Customers` table.  That doesn't seem right.  `Customer` should be a primary key on this table.  You are missing a junction table to map between customers and products, which I would call `CustomerProducts`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  Customers.Customer,
  Products.ProductID,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Products.ProductID in ('ab6','ab5','ab4','ab3','ab2','ab1','abc'.......many others THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Product_10,
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Products ON Customers.ProductID = Products.ProductID
WHERE Products.ProductID in ('ab6','ab5','ab4','ab3','ab2','ab1','abc'......)
GROUP BY Customers.Customer, Products.ProductID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Customers.Customer, Products.ProductID, COUNT(1) as Product_10
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Products 
    ON Customers.ProductID = Products.ProductID
WHERE Products.ProductID in ('ab6','ab5','ab4','ab3','ab2','ab1','abc'.......many others)
GROUP BY Customers.Customer, Products.ProductID
```

If your DBMS supports it you can get a total per Customer with grouping sets:

```
SELECT Customers.Customer, coalesce(Products.ProductID, 'Total'), COUNT(1) as Product_10
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Products 
    ON Customers.ProductID = Products.ProductID
WHERE Products.ProductID in ('ab6','ab5','ab4','ab3','ab2','ab1','abc'.......many others)
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((Customers.Customer, Products.ProductID),(Customers.Customer));
```

Group by Rollup and Group by Cube may be other constructs you are interested in